# Can you attach an AudioContext/Analyser to an HTML audio node with a src already loaded?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a basic HTML audio src, and I'm just trying to hook an analyzer node to the output of it to show a visualizer when you play the file. Any ideas?

When I try to map the node, I also get stuttering. When I make an AudioContext and attach it to the source, I get no output. I'm sure I'm just routing/doing it wrong. Any help? Thanks in advance!

The js:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{

  const audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const co = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
  const audioSrc = "https://pineprojectmusic.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/StreamingSongs/Radio.mp3";
  var track;
  
  // Fetch mp3
  
  
  audio.addEventListener("play", function() 
  {
    // Circumvent Chrome autoplay AudioContext issues
    if (audioCtx.state === "suspended")
      {
        audioCtx.resume()
      };
    
    // Where we add connect all of the analyser stuff
    // track = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    // track.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    
    if (this.dataset.playing === "false")
    {
        alert("Playing");
        audio.play();
      this.dataset.playing = true;
    } else if (this.dataset.playing === "false")
    {
      alert("Stopped");
      audio.pause();
      this.dataset.playing = true;
    }
    
  }, false);
  
  function setUpContext()
  {
    if (typeof audioCtx != 'undefined')
      {
        audioCtx.resume();
      }
  }
  // var source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  

  


  
  // Where we fetch the mp3 file from S3 Bucket
  
  /*
  fetch(co + audioSrc)
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(data => loadSong(data)); */

function loadSong(data)
{
  console.log(data);
  // This is where we assign the arrayBuffer into a stream and the src of the file.
  data.decodeAudioData(data);
  var mediaSrc = new MediaSource();
  var mediaBuffer = mediaSrc.createMediaElementSource(decodedAudio);
  audio.src.connect(analyser);
};
  
}); // end of DOM event
```

```css
#audio:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#thefile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

audio {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <audio id="audio" controls controlsList="nodownload" src="https://pineprojectmusic.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/StreamingSongs/Radio.mp3">
  </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: [This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API) might help.

Comment: I've used that as a resource, but here's the problem. the queried element is a string that represents a basic object, not a reference to the HTMLAudioElement. Therefore, I can't hook the context to the actual DOM element. Is there really no way to capture a reference to the HTML-embedded Audio element through js? It's just grabbing the string value, and I can't seem to find a way to type cast in JS (I'm used to strongly-typed C#)

I'd like to set the audio el and source in HTML, and just hook the vis to the HTML in js. Can't find a solution.

Comment: I should mention when I just connect a context instance to the queried audio element, it stutters like crazy. The minute I take the context away, it's perfect again. Something is going on. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues I found that solved it for me:

1. I forgot to add a `<AllowedHeader>` entry in my S3 CORS policy (derp).
2. Because of web browsers' new autoplay stuff, you have to instantiate a new instance of the AudioConext *after* a user interaction (I put mine in the "play" event listener for the audio tag).

The audio now passes, and we're off to the races it seems! Hope this helps somebody in the future! :)

The code (to hopefully help some in the same boat in the future):

```
// Declare variables
const url = "https://pineprojectmusic.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/StreamingSongs/Radio.mp3";
var AudioContext = (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
// if (audioCtx) { audioCtx = new (audioCtx) };
var source, analyser, ctx;

// Housekeeping when DOM loads
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () 
{
    // Make Audio File
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.id = "audio";
    audio.src = url;
    audio.controls = true;
    audio.controlsList = "nodownload";
    audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    audio.autoload = "auto";

    // Create Canvas
    const canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    canvas.id = "canvas";
    canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Insert it into HTML
    document.getElementById("audio_container").appendChild(audio);
    document.getElementById("audio_container").appendChild(canvas);

    audio.addEventListener("play", playAudio);

    function playAudio()
    {
        // Set up routes
        const audioCtx = new(AudioContext);
        if (!analyser) 
        { 
            analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
            analyser.fftSize = 256;
        };
        if (!source) 
        { 
            source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
            source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        };
        audioAnalyser();
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a wrong routing.

The spec has described the [Modular Routing](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#ModularRouting) topic well.
So the key point is:

In AudioContext, signal goes from a source to a destination, optionally through other audioNodes.
Hence we have to connect them in the right order:

**Source --> Analyser --> Destination**

See the example below:

```js
const audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// Get the source
const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.onplay = () => audioCtx.resume();
const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);

// Create an analyser
const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = 2 ** 8;
const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

// Connect parts
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

// Visualisation
const section = document.querySelector('section');
const v = (new Array(bufferLength)).fill().map(e => (e = document.createElement('i')) && section.appendChild(e) && e);

setInterval(() => {
  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);
  dataArray.forEach((d, i) => v[i].style.setProperty('--c', Math.abs(128 - d) * 2.8125 | 0))
}, 15);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh
}

section i {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  height: calc(100vh * var(--c)/360);
  border-radius: 55%;
  background: hsl(var(--c), 95%, 45%);
}

audio {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  opacity: .3
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<audio controls src="https://ice3.somafm.com/defcon-128-mp3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This snipped doesn't work for me. The new issue I've come across is a CORS outputting zeroes when I invoke audioCtx.createElementMediaSource(audio). I've already retrieved the mp3 via CORS, so why is it failing? If I set cross-origin to 'anonymous' it breaks even further and won't even play. Why is this so confusing?

Comment: @JoelHager, sorry, I made it in Firefox only and didn't test it in Chrome. Now it works. CORS seems to be out of the scope of your question as you sated that audio was loaded. Anyway, congratulations, you've made it! =))

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` to the CORS config. Ugh. lol